# How do I open Vim at a Rust program's `main` function?

Tags: vim, rust

I'm in the terminal, I `cd <projectdirectory>`. How can I open Vim positioned at the `fn main()` of this project.

I don't need a ready solution: ideas will be helpful. Could  I potentially make Vim use `racer` to jump to a symbol automatically on start?

Comment: This question might be too broad or elicit too many opinions. In any event, I'd look into using ctags for this. ctags will semantically index the code, and then you could use a shell command/alias to start Vim with the right filename and line number offset, or you could simply use the tag inside Vim to quickly navigate to that location.

Comment: The project may have multiple `fn main()`, or none at all.

Answer (score 8):

To open the file `main.rs` at the *first* line beginning with `fn main`, simply run:

```
$ vim main.rs +/'^fn main'
```

If you want every file named `main.rs` to automatically open to the first line beginning with `fn main`, you can add the following to your `.vimrc` file:

```
autocmd BufRead main.rs /^fn main
```

You can extend this to all files ending in `.rs` by changing `main.rs` to `*.rs`. However, if the file does not contain any matching lines, you will get an error message (`Error detected while processing BufRead Auto commands for <filename>`). The `silent!` command suppresses errors:

```
autocmd BufRead *.rs silent! /^fn main
```

This will search to `fn main` if it exists, but fail silently if it does not.

Comment: I was hoping for a more semantic approach, but that's a good start!

Comment: Yeah, I guessed maybe so, but that's outside of my expertise. Furthermore, "smarter" solutions can be more brittle, in a way -- as Sven pointed out in the question comments, a project may have any number of `main` functions, for example. Finally, I spent about half an hour on this answer, and that's probably more time than I will spend typing `vim src/main.rs` for the rest of my life! So I'm not all that willing to spend more time making it clever.